# OpenCV training output

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning

So I am creating my own classifiers using the OpenCV Machine Learning module for age estimation. I can train my classifiers but the training takes a long time so I would like to see some output (status classifier, iterations done etc.). Is this possible?  I'm using ml::Boost, ml::LogisticalRegression and ml::RTrees all inheriting cv::StatModel. Just to be clear i'm not using the given application for recognizing objects in images (opencv_createsamples and opencv_traincascade). The documentation is very limited so it's very hard to find something in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's an open feature request for a "progress bar" to provide some rudimentary feedback...  See https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/4881.  Personally, I gave up on using the OpenCV ML a while back.  There are several high-quality tools available to build machine learning models.  I've personally used Google's [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/), but I've heard good things about Theano and Caffe as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i've invested quite some time now in opencv for this so it's too late to chance. At least I know now it's not possibly without changing the source code. Caffe was my next step if I had more time.